# Running MapReduce program on Hadoop outputs only half of my data

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm running a simple MapReduce program on hadoop, calculating the min, max, median and stdev of values from a column of a dataset. When I run this locally on my computer, I get the final output calculated from all the values of the dataset. However, when I run this on Hadoop, the output corresponds to pretty much exactly half of the values from the dataset column. Code is below:

mapper.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import csv

# Load data
data = csv.DictReader(sys.stdin)

# Prints/Passes key-value to reducer.py
for row in data:
    for col, value in row.items():
        if col == sys.argv[1]:
            print('%s\t%s' % (col, value))
```

reducer.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import statistics

key = None
current_key = None
num_list = []
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Remove leading and trailng whitespace
    line = line.strip()

    # Parse input 
    key, value = line.split('\t', 1)

    # Convert string to int
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        # Skip the value
        continue

    if current_key == key:
        num_list.append(value)
    else:
        if current_key:
            print("Num. of Data Points %s\t --> Max: %s\t Min: %s\t Median: %s\t Standard Deviation: %s" \
                % (len(num_list), max(num_list), min(num_list), statistics.median(num_list), statistics.pstdev(num_list)))
        num_list.clear()
        num_list.append(value)
        current_key = key

# Output last value if needed
if current_key == key:
    print("Num. of Data Points %s\t --> Max: %s\t Min: %s\t Median: %s\t Standard Deviation: %s" \
                % (len(num_list), max(num_list), min(num_list), statistics.median(num_list), statistics.pstdev(num_list)))
```

Haddop Log:

```
2019-12-02 23:54:40,705 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1575141442909_0026
2019-12-02 23:54:47,903 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1575141442909_0026 running in uber mode : false
2019-12-02 23:54:47,906 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2019-12-02 23:54:54,019 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
2019-12-02 23:54:59,076 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
2019-12-02 23:55:00,115 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1575141442909_0026 completed successfully
2019-12-02 23:55:00,253 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 54
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=139868
                FILE: Number of bytes written=968967
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=501097
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=114
                HDFS: Number of read operations=11
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
                HDFS: Number of bytes read erasure-coded=0
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=2
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=2
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=7492
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=2767
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=7492
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=2767
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=7492
                Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=2767
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=7671808
                Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=2833408
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=10408
                Map output records=5203
                Map output bytes=129456
                Map output materialized bytes=139874
                Input split bytes=220
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=1
                Reduce shuffle bytes=139874
                Reduce input records=5203
                Reduce output records=1
                Spilled Records=10406
                Shuffled Maps =2
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=2
                GC time elapsed (ms)=80
                CPU time spent (ms)=2790
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=676896768
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=8266964992
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=482344960
                Peak Map Physical memory (bytes)=253210624
                Peak Map Virtual memory (bytes)=2755108864
                Peak Reduce Physical memory (bytes)=173010944
                Peak Reduce Virtual memory (bytes)=2758103040
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=500877
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=114
2019-12-02 23:55:00,254 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Output directory: data/output
```

Local Output:

```
# Data Points: 10407     Max: 89.77682042        Min: 13.87331897        Median: 46.44807153     Standard Deviation: 11.156280347146872
```

Hadoop Output:

```
# Data Points: 5203      Max: 89.77682042        Min: 13.87331897        Median: 46.202181       Standard Deviation: 11.28118280525746
```

As you can see the number of data points in the Hadoop output is almost exactly half of the full amount of data points from the local output. I tried using different datasets with different size and it's still always half...Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: @BenWatson I don't think so as my local output provides me with all the required data points, therefore, why would it be evaluating to false on hadoop but not locally?

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to do this in pyspark?

Comment: @cricket_007 It's a class assignment requiring using Hadoop

Comment: Spark can run on Hadoop. You mean MapReduce?

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out why I was getting such output. The reason is because Hadoop was splitting my input data in two for two separate mappers as I suspected. However, only the first half of the data retained the column headers of the dataset, therefore, when the second half of the dataset was being read by the mapper, the specified columns would not be accessed.

I removed the existing headers from the dataset and set the fieldnames when reading the data in order to fix my problem:

```
data = csv.DictReader(sys.stdin, fieldnames=("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"))
```